# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module Vue 3 PWA Workbox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, workbox

I am trying to convert my vue js app into a PWA. Following the workbox documentation in the following link:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies

I have to import some modules

```
import { registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing';
import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from 'workbox-strategies';
import { Queue } from 'workbox-background-sync';
```

After running npm run build, vue js automatically generates the following line of code which is at the top of service-worker.js file followed by the imports mentioned above:

```
importScripts("/precache-manifest.f6666fe9d8f679ee90db8a98ef900aa4.js", "https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js");
```

My app is fully functional without any errors, if I remove the imports, the service worker is registered successfully. When i add the imports I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Error during service worker registration: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://127.0.0.1:8887/') with script ('http://127.0.0.1:8887/service-worker.js'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed
```

From my research I have learned that the scripts need to be bundled using webpack or a similar service.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-bundlers

However since I am using the CDN to importScripts, according to my understanding it should automatically bundle as stated in the following website:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-sw

Answer (score 0):

It's an either-or thing: if you have full control over your build a bundling process, then following the "[Using bundlers with Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-bundlers)" guide and using the ES module `import {...} from '...'` syntax, but not using `workbox-sw`, would work.

If you don't have full control over your build process (and it sounds like you don't), then you can use [`workbox-sw` to load the rest of Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-sw). Since you already have the `importScripts('/path/to/workbox-sw.js')` in your service worker, using statements like `workbox.routing.registerRoute()` or `workbox.strategies.registerRoute()` in your service worker, and *not* putting in any `import {...} from '...'` statements, should just work.